# Getting “Errno 10061 No connection could be made error” when communicating with external APIs from my django application

Tags: python, django, windows-7

I keep getting the following error when communicating with the facebook api from an application running on my localhost:

```
<urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
```

My application is using a django package called “django social auth” (https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth) to authenticate users using the facebook graph api. The error occurs seems to occur when facebook redirects to my application – at the following URL:

http://localhost:8000/complete/facebook/?code=AQDXjgUiEmaWbO6fFuEiMqDicVDpFAEOy6qfptVP5OcSmHHS9qrTgclg3A1cKsJhw6XnFjqjHWdtclbvyGEKSiJUcbV0vAFbBU-HnPdOz0aPfS8uZMNuoC063U0VjU-7hFtVHe2V3UqjtiQVGwUjAfzd1dnxOtr6Y0b0owbrJBNxSAbtIAkWR1YVxYEuqFdSP_g

The error is only occurring on my personal machine (Windows 7, python 2.7.3, Chrome) – leading me to believe that this may be a Windows / Python problem – and not an application problem.  It does not occur on another machine running the same application using XP.

I have looked on the web for a solution to this error – but I couldn’t seem to find a definitive explanation of what to do to resolve the problem.  I really don’t want to have to change OS if that isn’t the only solution.

Comment: I'm surprissed this works at all on another machine because in my experience Facebook won't redirect to a URL such as `http://localhost:8000`, it requires a URL that looks real. For example I edited my hosts file so that my-dev-machine.com points to 127.0.0.1  and I configured the _site URL_ to be `http://my-dev-machine.com:8000` using the app configuration panel at Facebook website.

Comment: The redirect does seem to work on other machines - we have set our site URL to [http://localhost:8000](http://localhost:8000/)

Comment: Have you tried disabling the firewall on your machine?

Comment: Yes, the problem still occurs even with windows firewall disabled. I've also tried using different networks.

Comment: I guess no-one knows the answer :'(